# Octave - Increasing preview coordinate precision in plot

Tags: plot, octave, gnu

I want to manually truncate this signal into sections. On the bottom of the plot, there is a preview of the coordinates available when i put my mouse over the plot, I would like to know how can i increase the precision of the preview? (so it shows 24512 vs 2.451e+0004)

Otherwise is there any other methods where i can achieve the same goal? To find the X-pos to truncate the signals.

[desktop view of plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wguwL.png)

Comment: use "ginput" and collect the cutting points, then hit "Enter" if you are done. Your "cuttingpoint" are returned from ginput

Comment: Thanks for the help, andy!